# Assistance with MySQL 'LIKE' Statement

Tags: mysql

Hello all you beautiful people,

To preface my question, we have a database that stores the entire HTML code of a web form (don't ask, I didn't create this) and some of those HTML values are populated from a different table. This table was discovered to have some double quotes (`"`) in them, this is problem because if you have:

```
<input type="text" value="Hello "John" Smith">
```

It will break all of the tags below it.

We've gone ahead and fixed this, and I've implemented a solution to catch these from today onward. But now we have an unknown amount of forms that are broken.

So what I am trying to do is run an SQL statement to find all of the instances that this occurred.

Here is what I've got:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE data LIKE '%value="%"%"'
```

But this statement hasn't yielded any results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

DM

Comment: Throw a wildcard at the end also.  Right now, your LIKE statement is looking for something that _ends with_ what you have.  `'%value="%"%"%'` will cause it to look for something that _contains_ the pattern.

Comment: But - as a matter of practice, you're playing whack-a-mole.  There's LOTS of things that can cause this system to break, you're just dealing with one :)

Comment: @cale_b Thanks for your input! I am certainly aware that other things could break, but the devs have been good a snuffing out most of the bugs. I think this is just a residual one that I've been tasked with cleaning up temporarily.

The statement you provided gives me all results from the table, instead of the ones I'm looking for.

Comment: Just realized, to limit things, you may want to alter like so: `'%value="%"%"%>%`

Answer (score 0):

Your tags probably don't end with a quote, so let's add a wildcard at the end:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE data LIKE '%value="%"%"%'
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer! I have tried this statement but it just gives me everything.

Comment: @DanielM understood. Then we need to improve the filter. Can you give me an example for a result you did not desire to have?

Answer (score 0):

If the `value` attribute is the last attribute in an element you could check if the value of `value` if enclosed in double quotes in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE data
LIKE '%value="%"_%>'
```

The condition checks if there is double quote, before attribute value ends meaning incorrect value.

`_%` means one or more of any character.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It appears that this statement is giving me all results instead of the one's I'm looking for.